# Will the tubelight fit in the holder, in both frames?

Tags: special-relativity

I have a tubelight holder and my friend has a tubelight which is longer in length than the holder. I told my friend to run at high speed so that tubelight contracts (lorentz contraction). While he's running I took the tubelight from him and kept it between the two ends, while retarding in my refrence frame the tubelight began to expand and broke the rear end. Now if this phenomenon is seen by my friend the tubelight was much larger than the holder and when he gave it two me, it started contracting due to increase in speed w.r.t. him. Maximum it can contract will still be larger then the holder due to having rest length more then holder. So the question is when the tubelight didn't get completly into the holder, in my friends frame, how did it break in the rear end?

Comment: Sounds like a variant of the [ladder paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ladder_paradox).

Answer (score 1):

Lorentz contraction is not really a contraction. Instead it is a rotation, but it is a rotation in spacetime. One end of the object rotates forward in time while the other end rotates backwards in time. I explain this in detail in my answer to ["Reality" of length contraction in SR](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/148216/reality-of-length-contraction-in-sr).

In your frame you bring both the ends of the tube to a halt at the same time. The tube returns to its normal length and shatters.

However in the rest frame of the tube its ends are brought to a stop at different times, and as a result the tube shatters.

So both observers agree that the tube shatters due to a compressive stress, but they disagree about how that stress was created.

Comment: In my question I actually wanted to say that during expansion it broke the rear end of the holder. And tube was intact. On the other hand as you said, does it mean just like electric and magnetic forces, inertial force and compressive force by the ends of holder are same but frame dependent?

Comment: The actual question is how can a contracting tube break the holder outwards?