# Deriving length contraction from Lorentz transformation

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, coordinate-systems, inertial-frames

The formula for Lorentz transformation is
$\Delta x'=\gamma (\Delta x-v\Delta t)$ and
$\Delta t'=\gamma (\Delta t-\beta\Delta x/c)$

I was trying to derive length contraction from Lorentz transformation. Since length is just the position of two ends of an object at the same time, both $\Delta t'$ and $\Delta t$ should be $0$. When I plug $\Delta t'=\Delta t=0$ into the equation, I didn't really get $\Delta x'=\Delta x\gamma$. I have no idea why.

Comment: The derivation is done in ["Reality" of length contraction in SR](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/148216/reality-of-length-contraction-in-sr/270063#270063).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simultaneity is relative. You can't have $\Delta t=0$ in the first frame but also $\Delta t'=0$ for the other.

This derivation is a little tricky, because it seems like length contraction is just the spatial version of time dilation, but it's not. To describe length contraction, you need a spatially extended object, which sweeps out a ribbon through spacetime. So you should start by writing down equations for the parallel world-lines of the two ends of your object.